# Error Code: 1824. Failed to open the referenced table even though it is already created

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables

I am building a database for a school project, but for some reason I cannon make a foreign key reference between 2 tables (only those 2). My project has 14 tables and it works fine for all the others.

The tables are made like:

```
create table degree(
    title varchar(50),
    idryma varchar(40),
    bathmida enum('High School', 'Univercity', 'Master', 'PHD'),
    constraint degree_id primary key (title, idryma)
);

create table has_degree(
    degree_title varchar(50),
    degree_idryma varchar(40),
    employee_username varchar(12),
    acquisition_year year(4),
    grade float(3,1),

    constraint has_degree_id primary key (degree_title, degree_idryma, employee_username)
);
```

And then I try to alter the table so that I make the foreign key connections:

```
alter table has_degree add foreign key (degree_title) references degree(title);
alter table has_degree add foreign key (degree_idryma) references degree(idryma);
```

But I keep on getting

> Error Code: 1824. Failed to open the referenced table 'degree'

I have tried to make them like that:

```
create table degree(
    title varchar(50),
    idryma varchar(40),
    bathmida enum('High School', 'Univercity', 'Master', 'PHD'),
    constraint degree_id primary key (title, idryma)
);

create table has_degree(
    degree_title varchar(50),
    degree_idryma varchar(40),
    employee_username varchar(12),
    acquisition_year year(4),
    grade float(3,1),

    foreign key (degree_title) references degree(title),
    foreign key (degree_idryma) references degree(idryma),
    
    /*employee is an other table that I use and that works just fine*/

    foreign key (employee_username) references employee(employee_username),
    constraint has_degree_id primary key (degree_title, degree_idryma, employee_username)
);
```

But the only thing that changes is that I get

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'has_degree_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'degree'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns in your foreign key in table `has_degree` must be the same as the columns in the primary key of the referenced table `degree`.

In this case, the primary key of `degree` consists of two `varchar` columns.

So the foreign key in `has_degree` that references it must also be only two `varchar` columns, and values in those columns in `has_degree` must match exactly the values in a row of `degree`.

You defined the foreign key this way:

```
foreign key (degree_title) references degree(title),
foreign key (degree_idryma) references degree(idryma),
```

But that's *two* foreign keys, each having a single column. You need one foreign key with two columns:

```
foreign key (degree_title, degree_idryma) references degree(title, idryma),
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that it had to be that way! Thank you